# Why do I get the message "TypeError: 'complex' object is not subscriptable" when trying to use a complex number in a np.sum?

Tags: python

Am trying to write code for an equation that includes complex number, and put it into a function for simpsons rule.

```
import numpy as np
import cmath as cmp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wavelength = 0.000001 #meters
Apw = 0.00002 # meters Apw taken as apeture width
z = 0.02 # meters
N = 100
permittivity = 0.00000000000885418783
c =  299792458 # m/s
k = (2*cmp.pi)/wavelength
j = 0 + 1j
n = 100



x = np.linspace(-0.005, 0.005, n, 1.1)

def simps (N, k, Apw, x):
  S = 0
  h = Apw / N
  for i in range(0, N + 1):
    for xprime in range(0, N+1):
        xprime = Apw*xprime/N
        f =  cmp.exp(((j*k)/(2*z))*(x-xprime)**2)
    if (i != 0) and (i != n):
      f *= (2 + (2 * (i % 2)))
    S = h/3 * np.sum(f[0:-1:2] + 4*f[1::2] + f[2::2])
  return S

x = np.linspace(-0.005, 0.005, n, 1.1)

I = np.zeros([n])

for i in range(0,n):


    E_0 = simps(N, k, Apw, x[i])[0]
    I[i] = permittivity*c*(E_0 * cmp.conj(E_0)).real
```

Where j is a complex number j = 0 + 1j
I don't really know if what I am doing is anywhere near correct, the lines that are causing the error is line 46 and 36

Comment: Please add the entire stacktrace and what values you used when you called `simps`, it makes it easier to understand :)

Comment: What is `f`?  The most straightforward answer is that it is a complex number, which isn't subscriptable, as the error you are getting says.  Please supply the full stack trace of the error you are getting, and let us know which line of your source is the cause of the error (since we don't have line numbers on your code).

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this and I am new to python, my university offers no proper teaching of python and basically expect us to understand it all already.

Comment: "the lines that are causing the error is line 46 and 36" is not very helpful to those reading your question. Those line numbers only make direct sense in the context of your IDE. Your intention behind `f[1::2]` isn't clear so your question is hard to answer. What do you expect `f[1::2]` to be? Is that supposed to be the real part of the complex number `f`?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `f` is a complex number.  As the error message says, you can subscript (use square braces on) a complex number.  For this reason, the expressions `f[0:-1:2]`, `f[1::2]` and `f[2::2]` are illegal operations that are producing this error. It seems that maybe you think that `f` is a list of complex values, rather than a single value?

If you do know that `f` is a single complex value, then the only operations on it that I can think of are to extract the real and imaginary parts with `f.real` and `f.imag`.